# Extract p-value from an Object QuadTypeIndependenceTest and ScalarIndependenceTest from Coin Packages

Tags: r, p-value, statistical-test

Using `Aids2` dataset from package `MASS`, I am applying Ansari-Bradley Non-Parametric Test to test Group Independency by this snippets

```
library(coin)
library(MASS)
a1 <- ansari_test(Aids2$diag~Aids2$state)
a2 <- ansari_test(Aids2$diag~Aids2$sex)
```

if I take a peek of a1 and a2 object it gives summary like this:

```
Asymptotic K-Sample Ansari-Bradley Test

data:  Aids2$diag by Aids2$state (NSW, Other, QLD, VIC)
chi-squared = 4.4829, df = 3, p-value = 0.2138

Asymptotic Two-Sample Ansari-Bradley Test

data:  Aids2$diag by Aids2$sex (F, M)
Z = -1.6765, p-value = 0.09364
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of scales is not equal to 1
```

with the respective object class is:

```
> class(a1)
[1] "QuadTypeIndependenceTest"
attr(,"package")
[1] "coin"
> class(a2)
[1] "ScalarIndependenceTest"
attr(,"package")
[1] "coin"
```

However since I am only interested to the p-value **(p-value = 0.2138)**, I would like only to extract that from the object, but I couldnt find how to extract it..

Comment: Try `pvalue(a1)`. It's a function of `coin` package that helps extracting p-values.

Comment: @AntoniosK ouch.. thanks it worked!, it was so simple, but I missed it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since object like `"QuadTypeIndependenceTest"` and `"ScalarIndependenceTest"` are created from the results of `coin` packages, there is specific function to extract the pvalue, using `coin::pvalue(obj)`, Special thanks for pointing @AntoniosK